# Safari 8 Not Showing Network Requests when using the web inspector/develop tools

Tags: macos, network, safari

I have a feeling that I may have toggled some settings, but I can't find it anymore.

Basically I am trying to monitor requests sent from my webapp. The usual method is Inpect Element -> Timelines -> Network Requests, where Safari gives me a graph and a list of all the requests made.

Now I can see the graph, but I can't see the list of the requests made.

Here's a screenshot illustrating where I'd like to see the requests:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Deselect timeline (between 10 and 12 seconds)